# Mostrar respuesta de un Http.get en Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, system.js

Estoy tratando de aprender `Typescript` y `Angular2`. Lo que hago es consultar un servicio publico al momento de hacer click e imprimo la nota celebre, pero  estoy obteniendo el siguire error:

```
Cannot read property 'quotes' of undefined in [{{quote.contents.quotes.quote}} in App@4:20]
```

Mi Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<ul>
                <li (click)='myAlert()'> Helow World</li>
             </ul>
             <div>
              <spam>{{quote.contents.quotes.quote}}</spam>
             </div>`,
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class App {
  public quote: Object;
  public  logError: string;

  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.quote = {};
  }

  myAlert(){
      this.http.get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json").map(res => { return res.json()})
        .subscribe(
          data => this.quote = data,
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );

  }
}
```

Mi boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {App} from './component'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>


    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/http.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Como hago para obtener la respuesta del servicio en el subscriber y colocarla en el template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce porque, antes de obtener los datos de servidor, la propiedad `quote` de tu componente tiene un objeto vacío y el valor de `quote.contents` es `undefined`

Creo que lo podrías solucionar guardando en dicha propiedad el texto de la cita directamente.

El código del método `myAlert` quedaría así:

```
myAlert(){
  this.http.get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json").map(res => { return res.json()})
    .subscribe(
      data =>  this.quote = data.contents.quotes[0].quote,
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );
}
```

Y en la plantilla lo usarías así: `<spam>{{quote}}</spam>`

Comment: Justo di con esta solución. Gracias de igual forma.